# Part of object to return is during runtime subtype, but is returned as supertype from controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller

I have a controller method which returns OkObjectResult(profile). profile is a custom type with many fields. I set one of these fields' subfield to be of a specific type during runtime. When I trigger the method in debug, I can see that the field I wish to change the type of, changes type. However, once I run

```
return new OkObjectResult(profile);
```

the type I see has changed in debug, is no longer changed in the result.

profile is of type Sokeresultat:

```
[DataContract]
  public class Sokeresultat
  {
     [DataMember(Name = "treff", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "treff")]
     public List<MeldingV1> Treff { get; set; }
  }
```

The field I during runtime change type of is within MeldingV1:

```
[DataContract]
  public class MeldingV1
  {
    [DataMember(Name = "meldingMetadata", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "meldingMetadata")]
    public MeldingMetadata MeldingMetadata { get; set; }
  }
```

Durin runtime I set MeldingMetaData to be of type ForsendelseV2, which inherits from MeldingMetaData:

```
[DataContract]
  public class ForsendelseV2 : MeldingMetadata
  {
     [DataMember(Name = "tittel", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tittel")]
     public string Tittel { get; set; }
  }
```

During debug, I can see that the MeldingMetadata object does have a field called "Tittel", but this is never returned...
I see this before I execute the return statement, so there are no other statements that could alter the type.

Comment: Did you assign teh same, single instance to multiple reference variables/fields? While i do not understand that pattern, it certainly sounds like that old issue.

Comment: @Christopher, no. This is what happens in my controller
var profile = await someService;
return new OkObjectResult(profile);

Comment: Did the profile variable change *in any way* between those calls? Is it suppsoed to change between calls?

Comment: No and no. I wish it changed.. but there are literally no other statements occuring.

Comment: If nothing is changing profile, *why would it change on it's own*? Do you got some wierd setup where `OkObjectResult()` changes something in the profile? You are a programmer- things do not happen until you **make** them happen!